# Stack with circular progress bar and elevated button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm wanted to achieve the following UI in the screenshot and achieved by the below code on two different phones. But the same is not working on many other devices. Is there a way to handle the size of `CircularProgressIndicator`(currently I'm using `Transform.scale()` which is not giving me generic result) so that it fits around the sibling container inside the stack?

Edit:
The reason for using `CircularProgressIndicator` is to show progress.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaq = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
      Transform.scale(
        scale: mediaq.width <= 360 ? 2.35 : 2.70,
        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.orange,
          strokeWidth: .75,
          value: 1,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.orange],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.transparent,
              fixedSize: Size(mediaq.width * .24, mediaq.height * .12),
              shape: const CircleBorder(side: BorderSide.none),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("child")),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please attach the resulted screenshot of other devices ? and also device information.

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan the device of the above screenshot is of pixel 4a. the width is 392.72 and height is 753.45.

Comment: you said the same is not working on the other devices. what are those devices? what is the result? how is it different from the desired result ?

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan iPhone SE for instance does not display anything. W:320, H:568.

Answer (score 1):

Re wrote your code and here is my output

```
Transform.scale(
    scale: mediaq.width> 375 ? 3.10 : 2.35,
    child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      color: Colors.white,
      strokeWidth: .75,
      value: 1,
    ),
  ),
```

Output:
Iphone 12 Pro Max (W:428 , H:926)
[image]

Iphone SE (Second Generation) (W:375, H: 667)
[image]

Also you can try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) for responsive ui.

Comment: In the case of an iPad, this won't work.

Comment: I just compared 2 screen size. If you want complete responsive ui then you have to use screenutils or similar package or you have to write your own responsive code. 
Example:     scale: mediaq.width > 375 && mediaq.width < 1000
            ? 3.10
            : mediaq.width > 1000
                ? 5.00
                : 2.35,

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flutter_screenutil** package to make your UI more responsive, instead of MediaQuery.

I have done your screen using **flutter_screenutil** package.
Please try this out. I assumed the heights, widths, and radius. You can modify these as per your requirement. I have also attached the UI I got.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(375, 667),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        builder: () {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: const ButtonTest(),
          );
        });
  }
}

class ButtonTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ButtonTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonTestState createState() => _ButtonTestState();
}

class _ButtonTestState extends State<ButtonTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 94.h, // You can change here
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(
              2.0.w, // You can change here
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("Button Pressed");
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 92.h, // You can change here
                width: 92.h, // You can change here
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.orange,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'child',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]